# Word VSTO override CTRL+Z / CTRL+Y

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm looking for a way to override Undo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) / Redo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) commands in Word 2010 (C# + VSTO).
Is it possible ?

I managed to catch Copy / Paste commands, but it seems that Undo / Redo are not commands in RibbonUI like Copy / Paste.

Comment: @udondan - Care to tell how u captured copy/paste events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want some control over what happens with Undo/Redo, check out Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.UndoRecord.  Here's [the thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsto/thread/275d275f-c569-445a-8d9c-631e01bd1f46) where I learnt to use it properly!

If you want to catch the actual keystrokes, then you're in Windows API land.  So generally, Google terms related to that. But [message-hooks-in-add-ins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2009/02/24/message-hooks-in-add-ins.aspx) may be useful to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I don't see how this link can help me.
This link just show how to add a custom record into undo / redo drop down list.
What I want is to catch Ctrl+Y / CTRL+Z.

There are no events in UndoRecord class.

Comment: I'm surprised that there are no other way to do this.
I think using global hook means using heavy artillery.

Comment: Here is the VSTO Keyboard Hooking I use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10257266/495455