# Alternative way to disable shortcut in Excel

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-addins

In Excel 2007-2013 I used Application.OnKey to disable shortcuts

```
Application.OnKey("{F5}", "")
```

But in Excel 2016 it provokes crashes of Excel (it explodes later, then I press F5). I suppose it is some bug in new Excel, maybe someday it is going to be fixed, but right now I need a workaround, another way to disable shortcuts. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses:`Application.Onkey "{F5}",""`

Comment: @BruceWayne I cannot, It's C#, but in VB.NET and VBA it is the same - crash, even without parentheses

Comment: Try using just a regular key and see if it crashes. I wonder if it's the key `{F5}` or `ÒnKey` generally.

Comment: @BruceWayne OnKey generally, F5 just for example

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193055/how-to-perform-onkey-event-in-an-excel-add-in-created-with-visual-studio-2010) help at all? Or any of [these](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vsto%20excel%20application.onkey) results?

Comment: @BruceWayne I know how to use google search and I'm afraid my question is not about how to use Application.OnKey, but how to avoid it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry! I have been searching and can't find a way to stop short cuts.  Is there a specific one you want to stop that we can perhaps tackle another way?

Comment: I have specific five to disable:) Ctrl+F3, F3, F5, Ctrl+F8 and F8. I use them for other purposes in my add-in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102520/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-alex-butenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to avoid crashes:

First step is to set something else, not empty string in `Application.OnKey`

```
Application.OnKey("{F5}", " ")
```

If you just leave it alone, Excel will show the message about wrong macro name.

I removed this message temporarily setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = false` when key event happens:

```
static int HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    if (nCode < 0) {
        return (int) WinApi.CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        ExcelAddIn.ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        ExecuteAsync(() => {
            ExecuteInUIThread(() => {
                OnKeyPress((uint) wParam);
                Application.DisplayAlerts = true;
            });
        });
    }
    return (int) WinApi.CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

But after that I found that this bug is fixed already and [fix version](http://winaero.com/blog/microsoft-office-2016-16-0-6366-2062-is-out-for-office-insiders/) is goning to be released soon (if not yet).