# Outlook Add-in Ribbon Tab and ContextMenu Item using one Ribbon file

Tags: vb.net, outlook, contextmenu, ribbon-control

I currently have an Outlook Add-in that has a Ribbon Group with buttons(Designer) in it and all that works fine. I have a contextmenuItem that I have added via a Ribbon Designer (XML) that looks something like that:

**Context Menu Button:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
  <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
    <button id="MyContextMenuMailItem"
    label="Record To History"
    onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
  </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

**Ribbon Tab:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabMail" insertAfterMso="GroupContactFind">
                <group id="RollbaseSettingsGroup" label="Rollbase Settings">
                    <button id="MyButton" onAction="MyButton_Click" label="MyButton" size="large" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I can get my ribbon to work seperately without specifying the below code but my ContextMenu doesn't show and I can get my ContextMenu to work seperately but my Ribbon Code doesn't show. Could you suggest me as to where am I going wrong so that I can show both the contextmenu and the ribbon together.

**Code:**

```
' This will allow the contextmenuItem to appear on an email Item
    Protected Overrides Function CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() As Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility
        Return New ContextMenuRibbon() 'This only does the contextmenu
    End Function
```

Now I would like to Add this contextmenuitem To my current Ribbon Item's code so that I can access both in one go. Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?
I have read this and done everything that it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652837/how-to-have-a-vsto-ribbon-and-context-menu-at-the-same-time) but the only difference is that my Ribbon is a Ribbon Designer whereas my ContextMenuItem is a Ribbon XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine both XML parts into a single one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab idMso="TabMail" insertAfterMso="GroupContactFind">
            <group id="RollbaseSettingsGroup" label="Rollbase Settings">
                <button id="MyButton" onAction="MyButton_Click" label="MyButton" size="large" />
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
<contextMenus>
   <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <button id="MyContextMenuMailItem"
              label="Record To History"
              onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
    </contextMenu>
 </contextMenus>
 </customUI>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that but I lose my icons. Moreover, I have to transfer each and every function into my custom Ribbon UI code. Correct?

Comment: I don't know how you lose your icons, but you can use the getImage callback to load them dynamically.

Comment: Ok let me give it a try. Will get back to you.